# VSCode Style/PercentLiteralDelimiters rule not being respected in ruby files

Tags: ruby, visual-studio-code, chef-infra

Please help me I am being tortured by the linting squiggly and I cannot get rid of it. Here is the context

working in vscode 1.37.0

on a chef project (mostly ruby syntax)

I have the [chef extension](https://github.com/pendrica/vscode-chef) installed and chefdk installed an available in my path

And for the life of me I cannot get the linting warning for `Style/PercentLiteralDelimiters` to go away. I will get this warning when I am using `[]`

[image]

Then if I make the suggested change to `()` it wants me to flip it the other way.

[image]

I get the same results if I specify this rule in my rubocop.yml

```
Style/PercentLiteralDelimiters:
    Enabled: true
    PreferredDelimiters:
        default: '[]'
```

I know this is an obscure issue and if there is any further information that would help I will be happy to supply it but for my sanity I would really like to figure this out.

#### Update

Running rubocop from the command line does not report any issue. I believe that vscode is using chefdk's foodcritic. As according to the extension `If you have the ChefDK installed, Foodcritic should "just work" on Windows`. My understanding is foodcritic is just rubocop with a special config for chef style conventions. But even running foodcritic from the command line does not seem to report these as an issue.

I have even tried to be explicit in the vscode workspace settings, by setting the configFile path for both rubocop and foodcritic but this has not changed anything. Seems more and more like an issue the extension. Found this issue that sounds related. Might just have to watch this issue https://github.com/pendrica/vscode-chef/issues/29

Comment: what is the error when you execute rubocop directly using the command line?

Comment: Foodcritic and Rubocop are different stuff. Foodcritic checks your resources and not code style like Rubocop. However ChefDK indeed comes with a built-in "cookstyle", a gem based on rubocop and predefined rules for Chef recipes. Some of the rules in Cookstyle and Rubocop are conflicting - and %w is one of them. I don't use vscode, so I can't help you any further here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So thanks to the comment from Draco Alter I was able to figure out the issue I had.

First I had a miss understanding about Foodcritic and was conflating it with cookstyle. After understanding that and the comment that Draco made saying

> Some of the rules in Cookstyle and Rubocop are conflicting - and %w
>   is one of them.

I figured I would favor cookstyle as I am using ruby exclusively for chef. So I ensured rubocop was gone `gem uninstall rubocop` and then I just needed to update my vscode workspace settings to have from

```
{
    "ruby.lint": {
--        "rubocop": true
++        "cookstyle": true
    }
}
```